# Is there a function in java to get moving average

Tags: java

I have a situation where I need to process 5000 samples from a device in every 0.5 sec.

Lets say the window size is 100, then there would be 50 points resulting from the moving average. I am trying with conventional method, i.e. with loops. But this is a very inefficient way to do it. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Did you already read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average, specially "Weighted moving average"

Comment: A weighted moving average is much simpler to calculate, much faster and in many cases a more useful value to calculate. i.e. it is use in modeling many systems.

Comment: I do think that __the thing you mentioned is not called moving average__,     Moving average is something like, let says 5days moving average,  `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`   will become `[nan, nan, nan, nan, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0]`

Answer (score 29):

Check out the [Apache Maths](http://commons.apache.org/math/) library. This has methods for doing precisely what you want. See [DescriptiveStatistics](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/descriptive/DescriptiveStatistics.html) and [Mean](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/descriptive/moment/Mean.html) for more info.

Comment: Hello, I checked the library. Which method does the moving average? I cant seem to find it

Comment: DescriptiveStatistics optionally does moving average

Comment: In case your'e like me and found this hard to follow, this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43420275/track-multiple-moving-averages-with-apache-commons-math-descriptivestatistics shows that - "I track the 10 minute moving average of the metric by using the setWindowSize(10) method on DescriptiveStatistics."

Comment: I don't see in the documentation that `DescriptiveStatistics` is using moving average. Even more so, it's stated that it saves the elements, based on a window (which can be infinite :scream:). `Mean` on the other hand is `AbstractStorelessUnivariateStatistic` which probably doesn't store the elements, though not explicitly stated.

Answer (score 23):

Here's one way.

```
public class Rolling {

    private int size;
    private double total = 0d;
    private int index = 0;
    private double samples[];

    public Rolling(int size) {
        this.size = size;
        samples = new double[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) samples[i] = 0d;
    }

    public void add(double x) {
        total -= samples[index];
        samples[index] = x;
        total += x;
        if (++index == size) index = 0; // cheaper than modulus
    }

    public double getAverage() {
        return total / size;
    }   
}
```

---

```
public class RollingTest extends TestCase {

    private final static int SIZE = 5;
    private static final double FULL_SUM = 12.5d;

    private Rolling r;

    public void setUp() {
        r = new Rolling(SIZE);
    }

    public void testInitial() {
        assertEquals(0d, r.getAverage());
    }

    public void testOne() {
        r.add(3.5d);
        assertEquals(3.5d / SIZE, r.getAverage());
    }

    public void testFillBuffer() {
        fillBufferAndTest();
    }

    public void testForceOverWrite() {
        fillBufferAndTest();

        double newVal = SIZE + .5d;
        r.add(newVal);
        // get the 'full sum' from fillBufferAndTest(), add the value we just added,
        // and subtract off the value we anticipate overwriting.
        assertEquals((FULL_SUM + newVal - .5d) / SIZE, r.getAverage());
    }

    public void testManyValues() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1003; i++) r.add((double) i);
        fillBufferAndTest();
    }


    private void fillBufferAndTest() {
        // Don't write a zero value so we don't confuse an initialized
        // buffer element with a data element.
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) r.add(i + .5d);
        assertEquals(FULL_SUM / SIZE, r.getAverage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Bug: if you call add method less than SIZE (specified in constructor), you get wrong average value. That's because there's a division by SIZE in getAverage(). 


We probably need another counter to take care of this case.

Comment: @sscarduzio  good catch.  I haven't tried it.  But the TestOne() test case looks fishy, too.  I suppose it could be accurate if the values in the list are assumed to be initialized to zero.  That's a fairly tortured requirement, however.  ;-)

Comment: It's not just inaccurate for value sets less than SIZE, this code is inaccurate for the last SIZE values of *every* set of values. Do not use.

Comment: It's not necessary to initialize the array to zeroes in the constructor.  Java guarantees that array types get default values.

Answer (score 9):

You can do that in O(1): keep a queue of the last 50 entries. When you add an entry and the queue is shorter 50 elements, just update the total and the count. If it is longer than 50 elements, update the total and the count as well. Pseudocode:

```
add(double x) {
    total += x;
    addToQueue(x);
    if (queueSize > 50) {
        total -= removeLastFromQueue();
    } else {
        count++;
    }
}
double getAverage() {
    return total / count;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Java 8 has added [`java.util.IntSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html). There similar classes for `Double` and `Long` as well. Fairly straightforward to use:

```
IntSummaryStatistics stats = new IntSummaryStatistics();
stats.accept(1);
stats.accept(3);
stats.getAverage(); // Returns 2.0
```

Comment: Best answer i have seen so far

Comment: The question is about moving average, not just about average.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a good implementation, using BigDecimal:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class MovingAverage {

    private final Queue<BigDecimal> window = new LinkedList<BigDecimal>();
    private final int period;
    private BigDecimal sum = BigDecimal.ZERO;

    public MovingAverage(int period) {
        assert period > 0 : "Period must be a positive integer";
        this.period = period;
    }

    public void add(BigDecimal num) {
        sum = sum.add(num);
        window.add(num);
        if (window.size() > period) {
            sum = sum.subtract(window.remove());
        }
    }

    public BigDecimal getAverage() {
        if (window.isEmpty()) return BigDecimal.ZERO; // technically the average is undefined
        BigDecimal divisor = BigDecimal.valueOf(window.size());
        return sum.divide(divisor, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know, there is no such function (class) in Java. But you can make one by yourself. Here is a simple example (SMA-Simple Moving Average):

```
public class MovingAverage {
    private int [] window;
    private int n, insert;
    private long sum;

    public MovingAverage(int size) {
        window = new int[size];
        insert = 0;
        sum = 0;
    }

    public double next(int val) {
        if (n < window.length)  n++;
        sum -= window[insert];
        sum += val;
        window[insert] = val;
        insert = (insert + 1) % window.length;
        return (double)sum / n;
    }
}
```

Comment: does it need both insert and n variables? i think it could be done with one variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
static int[] myIntArray = new int[16];
public static double maf(double number)
{
    double avgnumber=0;
    for(int i=0; i<15; i++)
    {
        myIntArray[i] = myIntArray[i+1];
    }
    myIntArray[15]= (int) number;
    /* Doing Average */
    for(int  i=0; i<16; i++)
    {
        avgnumber=avgnumber+ myIntArray[i];
    }
    return avgnumber/16;

}
```

this algorithm can also be called as Moving Average Filter which is working well for me ... i implemented this algo in my graph project!

Answer (score 0):

A solution without cumulative floating point errors.

```
/**
 * Voortschrijdend gemiddelde
 * @author Eelco de Lang
 */
public class MovingAverage
{
    private final double[] valuesWindow;
    private int fill;// = 0;

    public MovingAverage(int windowSize)
    {
        valuesWindow = new double[windowSize];
        assert windowSize > 0 : "Window size must be a positive integer";
    }

    public void add(long number)
    {
        add((double) number);
    }

    public void add(double number)
    {
        // Shift all values up 1 position
        System.arraycopy(valuesWindow, 0, valuesWindow, 1, valuesWindow.length - 1);
        valuesWindow[0] = number;
        if (fill < valuesWindow.length) {
            fill++;
        }
    }

    public double getAverage()
    {
        double result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < fill; i++) {
            result += valuesWindow[i];
        }
        if (fill == 0) {
            // Fine in most cases
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return result / fill;
        }
    }
}
public class MovingAverageTest
{

    @Test
    public void test()
    {

        MovingAverage movingAverage = new MovingAverage(2);
        Assert.assertEquals(0, movingAverage.getAverage(), 0.00001);
        movingAverage.add(0.5);
        Assert.assertEquals(0.5, movingAverage.getAverage(), 0.00001);
        movingAverage.add(1.5);
        Assert.assertEquals(1.0, movingAverage.getAverage(), 0.00001);
        movingAverage.add(1.5);
        Assert.assertEquals(1.5, movingAverage.getAverage(), 0.00001);
    }

    @Test
    public void test2()
    {
        MovingAverage movingAverage = new MovingAverage(3);
        Assert.assertEquals(0, movingAverage.getAverage(), 0.00001);
        movingAverage.add(123);
        Assert.assertEquals(123, movingAverage.getAverage(), 0.00001);
        movingAverage.add(123);
        Assert.assertEquals(123, movingAverage.getAverage(), 0.00001);
        movingAverage.add(123);
        Assert.assertEquals(123, movingAverage.getAverage(), 0.00001);
        movingAverage.add(123);
        Assert.assertEquals(123, movingAverage.getAverage(), 0.00001);
        movingAverage.add(123);
        Assert.assertEquals(123, movingAverage.getAverage(), 0.00001);
    }
}
```