# Any SDK function in Java to Push number unto a Stack and calculate the average?

Tags: java, android

I tried to Google for an answer but I think I am using wrong keywords. What I am trying to  do is - I have a collection of numbers (ints), and as I add new numbers I am computing the new average. I noticed that as my array grows, once I get to a certain count of elements (lets say 200), the calculation time becomes noticeable. I was wondering if there are any built-in SDK functions I can utilize to speed up my codes performance? I will be running the code on Android.

```
int[] numbers = new int[3];

private int average(int number){
    //some buildin operation to push in array an int?
    for(int i=0; i < numbers.length -1 ; i++){
        numbers[i]=numbers[i+1];
    }
    numbers[numbers.length -1] = number;
                    ;                
    //numbers[0] = numbers[1];
    //numbers[1] = numbers[2];
    //numbers[2] = number;

    int sum = 0;

    //any operation to get average?
    for(int i=0; i < numbers.length ; i++)
        sum = sum + numbers[i];

    //calculate average value
    double average = sum / numbers.length;

    return (int)average;
 }
```

Comment: not sure exactly what are you trying to achieve, do you want to get average value in an array?

Comment: I don't understand your question at all.  You want to calculate an average, but what is the problem?  What is that first loop in your code doing?

Comment: Please tell us what this function is suppsed to compute exactly.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I suspect that he's trying to calculate the running average.

Comment: the functoin does what it is supposed to do, but I will be getting an array of numbers between 200 en 500 values. where some mathimatic calculation happen. And the most work is in this function. So I was wondering if there are any build in function to do the same and will be they quicker than what I have..?

Comment: yes. partly it will be the running average.

Comment: This is what you want then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793400/is-there-a-function-in-java-to-get-moving-average

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I just made ​​myself a circular buffer (as suggested **Oli Charlesworth**).

And this is my implementation:

```
/** Circular buffer */
private class WindowBuffer {
    private final float [] values;
    private final int capacity;
    private float sum;
    private float average;
    private int head = -1;
    private boolean full = false;

    WindowBuffer(final int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        values = new float[capacity];
        for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
            values[i] = 0f;
        }
    }
    void clean() {
        if (head == -1) return;
        for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
            values[i] = 0f;
        }               
        sum = 0;
        average = 0;
        head = -1;
        full = false;
    }

    void put(final float value) {
        head++;
        if (head >= capacity) {
            head = 0;
            full = true;
        }
        sum -= values[head];
        sum += value;
        values[head] = value;
        calculateAverage();
    }

    private void calculateAverage() {
        if (full) {
            average = sum / capacity;
        } else {
            average = sum / (head + 1);
        }
    }

    float getAverage() {
        return average;
    }
}
```

UPD

```
void clean() {
            if (head == -1) return;
            if (full) {
                for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
                    values[i] = 0f;
                }
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i <= head; i++) {
                    values[i] = 0f;
                }
            }
            sum = 0;
            average = 0;
            head = -1;
            full = false;
        }
```

Comment: appreciated! this is almost what a came to. and its faster then what I had first

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see that my suggestion is appreciated ;)
Also, I truncated clean() fuction, see update.

Comment: my apologies :) it is appreciated now!

Answer (score 3):

A running average (on integer types) can be efficiently calculated as:

```
sum -= oldest_value;
sum += new_value;
avg = (double)sum / num_elements;
```

To avoid having to shift all your elements through your array each time, you should use your array as a [**circular buffer**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but here's one way:

```
public class RunningAverage
{
    ArrayList<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private int runningSum = 0;
    private int sampleSize;
    public RunningAverage(int[] initialSetOfValues)
    {
        if(initialSetOfValues == null || initialSetOfValues.length == 0)
        {
            // Abort gracefully
            // left as an exercise... 
        }
        sampleSize = initialSetOfValues.length;
        for (int num : initialSetOfValues)
        {
            numList.add(num);
            runningSum += num;
        }
    }

    public int getRunningAverage(int newestVal)
    {
        numList.add(newestVal);
        int oldestVal = numList.remove(0);

        runningSum = runningSum - oldestVal + newestVal;
        return runningSum / sampleSize;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        RunningAverage r = new RunningAverage(new int[]{4, 5 , 6, 7});
        System.out.println(r.getRunningAverage(8));
        System.out.println(r.getRunningAverage(9));
        System.out.println(r.getRunningAverage(10));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have been using an ArrayList if I were you. Take a look at a code that does exactly the same thing as your code do.

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private Integer average(Integer number){
    numbers.add(number);
    Integer sum = 0;    
    for(Integer num : numbers)  {
        sum = sum + num;
    }
    double average = sum / numbers.size();
   return (Integer)average;
}
```

And also, if you can save the variable sum for reuse, then you know how to find the new average for sure :)

Answer (score 0):

There aren't better algotithm that calculate the average. The optimized code (using the same data structure) would be:

```
private int average(int number){
      int sum = 0;
      for(int i=0; i<(numbers.length-1); i++){
          numbers[i] = numbers[i+1];
          sum += numbers[i];
      } 
      numbers[numbers.length -1] = number;

      return (int)((sum+number) / numbers.length);
}
```

Comment: There are better algorithms for calculating a **running** average, though.

Comment: ok but the first time you have to know the sum... the complexity has to be at least `O(n)`.

Comment: Assuming an infinite stream of input data, the amortized complexity is O(1).  And anyway, you typically assume `sum=0` at startup.

Comment: yep, if you have to calculate average _every_ element is as you said, in the case that you have to know average only in certain moment you add a useless costant effort `k`, so pushing an element in a simple array cost `O(n(1+k))` instead of `O(n)`...

Which algorithm choose dipends on what do you want to do! So i add +1 to your answer =)

Comment: And the other thing is that if you calculate a running average you have to use only that method to add elements in your structure... instead with my algorithm you can use also others ways to add when you have not to know the average.

Answer (score 0):

im struggling to understand your question and your code. i have no idea what that first loop is for at all.

but if your just trying to find the average your pretty much right

```
int sum =0;
for(int i=0; i<array.length();i++){
  sum=sum+array[i];
}
average = sum/array.length();
```

not the fastest way but every easy to read

Comment: =) I have trouble with my english too.
What I have is a new number pushed in to array.. of fixed size (first in last uit) than counting average. And performing some other operation with array. And than again... in a loop

Comment: as far as i understand this would still be find, just make sure you other operations aren't inside the average loops

Comment: oh i see what you meant now from Oli Charlesworth answer above. you are pushing some thing on and then pop and re calculating. glad you found an answer.