# Track multiple moving averages with Apache Commons Math DescriptiveStatistics

Tags: java, statistics, apache-commons, metrics, usage-statistics

I am using [DescriptiveStatistics](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math4/stat/descriptive/DescriptiveStatistics.html) to track the moving average of some metrics. I have a thread that submits the metric value every minute, and I track the 10 minute moving average of the metric by using the `setWindowSize(10)` method on DescriptiveStatistics.

This works fine for tracking a single moving average but I actually need to track multiple moving averages, i.e. the 1 minute average, the 5 minute average, and the 10 minute average.

Currently I have the following options:

1. Have 3 different DescriptiveStatistics instances with 3 different windows. However, this means we store the raw metrics multiple times which is not ideal.
2. Have 1 instance of DescriptiveStatistics and do something like the following when querying for a moving average:

   ```
   int minutes = <set from parameter>;
   DescriptiveStatistics stats = <class variable>;

   if (minutes == stats.getN()) return stats.getMean();
   SummaryStatistics subsetStats = new SummaryStatistics();
   for (int i = 0; i < minutes; i++) {
       subsetStats.addValue(stats.getElement((int)stats.getN() - i - 1));
   }
   return subsetStats.getMean();
   ```

However, option 2 means that I have to re-compute a bunch of averages every time I query for a moving average whose window is smaller than the DescriptiveStats window size.

Is there a way to do this better? I want to store 1 copy of the metrics data and continually calculate N moving averages of it with different intervals. This might be getting into the land of Codahale Metrics or Netflix Servo, but I don't want to have to use a heavyweight library just for this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `StatUtils` utility class and manage the array when adding new values. One alternative is to use `CircularFifoQueue` of [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/queue/CircularFifoQueue.html) with a size of 10 and Apache Utils to simplify the conversion to array of primitive values.

You can find an example of `StatUtils` in the [User Guide](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/stat.html), the following would be something similar to your use case.

```
CircularFifoQueue<Double> queue = new CircularFifoQueue<>(10);

// Add your values

double[] values = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(queue.toArray(new Double[0]))
mean1 = StatUtils.mean(values, 0, 1);
mean5 = StatUtils.mean(values, 0, 5);
mean10 = StatUtils.mean(values, 0, 10);
```