# calculate moving average without any special data structure

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I recently had an interview where I was given a situation in which I need to calculate moving average given a period. I came up with below solution but interviewer said he wanted me to do this without any special data structure because the DS will take some space? Is there any other better way to do this without any data structure?

```
public class MovingAverage {
  private final Queue<BigDecimal> window = new ArrayDeque<>();
  private final int period;
  private BigDecimal sum = BigDecimal.ZERO;

  public MovingAverage(int period) {
    this.period = period;
  }

  public void add(BigDecimal num) {
    sum = sum.add(num);
    window.add(num);
    if (window.size() > period) {
      sum = sum.subtract(window.remove());
    }
  }

  public BigDecimal getAverage() {
    if (window.isEmpty())
      return BigDecimal.ZERO;
    BigDecimal divisor = BigDecimal.valueOf(window.size());
    return sum.divide(divisor, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
  }
}
```

Comment: Theres a bunch of solutions here, perhaps you can find it; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793400/is-there-a-function-in-java-to-get-moving-average

Comment: Well no, you need to store the data somehow. Was he referring to accomplishing it without a queue?

Comment: *"without any **special** data structure"* might mean that interviewer wanted you to use an array. --- An `ArrayDeque` is just a wrapper around an array so it uses very little extra memory, especially compared to all the `BigDecimal` objects in the array, so the extra memory used by `ArrayDeque` vs plain array is minuscule, and a non-consideration. If interviewer insist on considering it, tell them they are wrong to waste time on that. --- However, the array size in the `ArrayDeque` could be managed to not be excessive large, by using `new ArrayDeque<>(period + 1)`

Comment: yeah maybe he wanted me to use double array instead of using `ArrayDeque` here I guess. Also using double instead of BigDecimal will help here in terms of memory or performance?

Comment: yeah agree with @Andreas he asked you to use simple data structure not ArrayDeque by the way why even you used AraayDeque when it can be done with the simple array? can you please tell me?

Comment: @RamanMishra Because `ArrayDeque` handles the queue aspect for you, so you don't have to write all that logic of keeping 2 index values, for head and tail.

Comment: I would argue that you've done it exactly the right way.  You chose the right data structure for the job, and (as far as I can see) implemented a correct solution.  Perhaps the interviewer was expecting you to put up an argument as to _why_ your solution is the best one.

Comment: @john If values can be `double` instead of `BigDecimal`, then I agree that storage requirement for `double[]` vs `ArrayDeque<BigDecimal>` is very different, so interviewer probably wanted `double[]` solution.

Comment: Are these values amounts of money? (I'm guessing because of the way you're rounding the average to two decimal places).  If so, the interviewer might have wanted you to argue that storing them in a `double[]` might be a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does a fixed length array count as a "special data structure"? If not you could do something like this:

```
public class MovingAverage {
  private final BigDecimal[] window;
  private final int period;
  private int size;
  private int idx;
  private BigDecimal sum = BigDecimal.ZERO;

  public MovingAverage(int period) {
    this.period = period;
    window = new BigDecimal[period];
  }

  public void add(BigDecimal num) {    
    if(size < period)
      size += 1;
    else 
      sum = sum.subtract(window[idx]);

    sum = sum.add(num);
    window[idx++] = num;
    if(idx == period) idx = 0;
  }

  public BigDecimal getAverage() {
    if (size == 0)
      return BigDecimal.ZERO;
    BigDecimal divisor = BigDecimal.valueOf(size);
    return sum.divide(divisor, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
  }  
}
```

Comment: Do we have to use BigDecimal here? How about using double[] instead of BigDecimal which can be more efficient?

Comment: @john no you do not need to use big decimal if you're confident all contents can fit inside a double

Comment: @john If you use doubles for this you can accumulate rounding errors, because subtracting the number at the end of the window might not perfectly cancel its addition at the beginning.   It takes some extra work to fix that.  I'm not sure if BigDecimal has the same problem.